# What does it mean if I don't receive a SMB Negotiate Protocol Response from server?

Tags: vpn, azure, server-message-block, wireshark, site-to-site-vpn

What does it mean to not get an SMB Negotiate Protocol Response from server? Unable to mount fileshare drive (a third-party fileshare outside Azure). The architecture is similar to this one: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-site-to-site-portal.

Note: I've tried everything, firewall on Azure side and on their side has ports open.

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n7DC.png)

Comment: Hi, I'm a reviewer reviewing this first-time question. I recommend adding more specific information. Can you describe you took (attempted to mount an SMB share, etc.).  Can you offer technical information (maybe describe a packet capture of the situation)?

Comment: Hey, the packet capture is in the link there. I cannot paste it as text though. Let me know if you can see it. I'm trying to mount a fileshare that's outside of Azure. It's a third-party